# Listeners hierarchy

Tags: java, android, listener, onclicklistener

I am wondering what is the listeners hierarchy in Java. 
For example, when I set two listeners like `onFocusChange` and `onClick` (those are just examples), which one will fire first? 
Can someone answer that question?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can answer this question as there are no provisions what the order is.

An implementation is free to fire the listeners in any order.

You can read the souce code of the class to get the concrete order for a certain implementation.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If I will set onFocusChangeListener (set button text to "Focus") and onClickListener (set button text to "Click") to one button and then press it, which text will appear? There have to be an order of that. As I understand, you comment that you can change it - could you please edit your post and include some sample code on how to do that?

Comment: @Marek you don't know which is fired first. Read the source code of the class you're using (from the android source) to know it. But it is not documented that this happens in a particular order.